# Bokeh chart with unknown amount of different types of columns

Tags: python, bokeh

If I have a bokeh chart in Python that has 3 String columns and n number of float columns, is it possible to write the bokeh chart with the n number of float columns formatted differently than the string columns?

for example:

```
df_left = (3 string columns)
df_right = (n float columns)

Columns = [TableColumn(field = x, title = x, format = (some format)) for x in df_left.columns, 
TableColumn(field = y, title = y, format = (some format) for y in df_right.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Columns = [TableColumn(field=x, title=x) for x in table_df_left.columns]

Columns += [TableColumn(field = y, title = y) for y in table_df_right.columns]
```

In case anyone finds this, this is how you would do it!